# How to prevent Xcode/Interface Builder from auto-shifting view down?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, interface-builder

Without modifying any code in a new Xcode 6.0 Single View project targeting iPhones running iOS 7.1, the result on my testing iPod Touch 5th gen device shows a shifted version of what's in Interface Builder.  It appears the shift is downward.  I've already tried turning off Auto Layout and Size Classes, and resetting all UIView coordinates to (0,0), but still the battery symbol and upper bar is too far down! Please see pictures below for Interface Builder screenshot, and device screenshot.  The question is how can I keep what I see in Interface Builder, and stop the iPod from shifting down the entire UIViewController?  Thanks!

[image: Interface Builder]
[image: iPod Touch 5th gen]

UPDATE: In the end, I had to go into project build settings, click on the app under Targets, and change Launch Images Sources to a new folder it titled "LaunchImage-2" and delete the Launch Screen File field, which was set to Launch Images.

[image: Launch Image Removal]

Comment: Looks like you need to add the 'Default' images into the project, have you done that?

Comment: No, what are Default images, and how do I add them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't add the Default-568h@2x.png

then xcode build the project of size 3.5 inch and shows black patch at the bottom.

So you have to compulsory add the image with name Default-568h@2x.png of size 640 x 1136

If you use an empty [Asset Catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html) for your Launch Images, the iPhone 5's screen size is supported (without having to include any image files at all).

Comment: Where can I find Default-568h@2x.png, and why did I not need to do this for all my other projects that I had before downloading Xcode 6.0?

Comment: Default-568h@2x.png is splash screen that will be shown when user opens the app.
that Means you have to create this image.

Comment: I don't want or need a splash screen, and none of my other apps (which I started before Xcode 6.0) has them. How can I turn off this requirement?

Comment: Okay, so I managed to add the LaunchImage catalog to the Images.xcassets, and left everything in there blank, but it still didn't remove all the black (3.5-inch) padding...

Comment: In my other projects, LaunchImage just has iPhone Portrait iOS 7,8... but for this new project, it has a ton of other blanks, for iPad, older iPhones, etc. etc.  It's so weird!

Comment: I stole the LaunchImage folder from a previous project created before Xcode 6.0.  It's a hack, solved my problem, but none of the proposed solutions is a panacea for this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need to add the default or launch images into the project. Your project should be using image assets, so there you will see launch images and you need to supply images of appropriate sizes, preferably for all iPhone screen sizes.

[image]

Comment: Where do I find these images? My background is just a generic UIView with no image content inside it, so I'm not sure how to generate Default Images. I never had to do this before (in Xcode 5, ...), so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: You should always have had these images in all of your previous apps. It should generally look like your initial UI but without the buttons.

Comment: Just FYI, these "default images" are not necessary.  They -- and the LaunchImages folder -- have always been blank for all of my projects.  Something changed in Xcode 6.0 where they were turned on by default, but with no images, and I had to get rid of them.